# Issue trying to insert records in temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an issue trying to insert records in temporary tables

I have a temporary table `#TmpCapacityTable`

```
CapacityDate    InstallerCode   WorkAreadID FoxtelCodeID    value
2/8/12      BAW     7       1510        3
2/8/12      BAW     7       1508        3
```

Second temporary table `#TmpAdjustmentTable`

```
CapacityDate    InstallerCode   WorkAreadID fFoxtelCodeID   value
2/8/12      BAW     7       1510        1
2/8/12      BAW     7       1508        1
2/8/12      BAW     7       1509        1
```

I need to insert into `#TmpCapacityTable` those rows that are not in but there are in `#TmpAdjustmentTable`, in the sample only code 1509

I'm using

```
Insert into #TmpCapacityTable
select * from #TmpAdjustmentTable 
    where #TmpAdjustmentTable.CapacityDate not in (select #TmpCapacityTable.CapacityDate from #TmpCapacityTable)  
    and   #TmpAdjustmentTable.WorkAreadID not in (select #TmpCapacityTable.WorkAreadID from #TmpCapacityTable)
    and   #TmpAdjustmentTable.InstallerCode not in (select #TmpCapacityTable.InstallerCode from #TmpCapacityTable)
    and   #TmpAdjustmentTable.FoxtelCodeID not in (select #TmpCapacityTable.FoxtelCodeID from #TmpCapacityTable)
```

but it doesn't work, I can't see what the problem is

Can Someone help me pleaseeee!!!

Thanks in advance

Eliana

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TmpCapacityTable(CapacityDate, InstallerCode, WorkAreaID, FoxtelCodeID, value)
    SELECT  ta.CapacityDate, ta.InstallerCode, ta.WorkAreaID, ta.FoxtelCodeID, ta.value
      FROM  #TmpAdjustmentTable ta
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #TmpCapacityTable tc
                ON  ta.CapacityDate     = tc.CapacityDate
                AND ta.InstallerCode    = tc.InstallerCode
                AND ta.FoxtelCodeID     = tc.FoxtelCodeID 
     WHERE  tc.value IS NULL
```

Comment: NOW I have the following problem whit it!!